# Animate text on swipe in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

I used this autoscroll viewpager [library](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager) and PagerAdapter to show images and Text. Then I used Animation to move the Text from left side to right side. Problem is the Animation does not occurs in every page of viewpager.
How to Animate the Text for every page ?

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<ModelObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] country = new String[] { "China", "India", "United States",
            "Indonesia", "Brazil", "Pakistan", "Nigeria"};

    int[] flag = new int[] { R.drawable.china, R.drawable.india,
            R.drawable.unitedstates, R.drawable.indonesia,
            R.drawable.brazil, R.drawable.pakistan, R.drawable.nigeria};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        ViewPagerAdapter swipeAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, country, flag);
        viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
                final float normalizedposition = Math.abs(Math.abs(position) - 1);
                page.setAlpha(normalizedposition);
            }
        });
    }

    public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        // Declare Variables
        Context context;
        String[] country;
        int[] flag;
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] country, int[] flag) {
            this.context = context;

            this.country = country;
            this.flag = flag;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return flag.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            // Declare Variables

            TextView txtcountry;
            ImageView imgflag;

            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagefrag, container, false);

            // Locate the TextViews in viewpager_item.xml

            txtcountry = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country);

            // Capture position and set to the TextViews

            txtcountry.setText(country[position]);
            txtcountry.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.myanim));

            // Locate the ImageView in viewpager_item.xml
            imgflag = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flag);
            // Capture position and set to the ImageView
            imgflag.setImageResource(flag[position]);

            // Add viewpager_item.xml to ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            // Remove viewpager_item.xml from ViewPager
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ViewPager.PageTransformer` interface in order to animate views inside of pages

```
class MyPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View page, float position) {
        float pageTimesPosition = page.getWidth() * position;
        View text = page.findViewById(R.id.text);
        if (text != null) {
            text.setAlpha(1.0f - position);
        }
    }
}
```

then with `viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new MyPageTransformer());` set you Transformer